# Modifying list according to parameters passed in the function

Tags: python, list

Hi guys so basically what my _build_url function does is it takes a list and then adds the parameters passed from the list to the url and generates a url.

```
def _build_url(list_here):
    pulls_url = "http://test.com" + '/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}'.format(list_here[0],list_here[1],list_here[2],list_here[3])
    print pulls_url #prints http://test.com/a/b/c/d



_build_url(["a","b","c","d]
```

I have passed 4 items in a list so the url is generated with 4 parameters, what If I want to pass only 2 parameters like _build_url(["a","b"]) and the url should be generated only from those two items in the list like #prints http://test.com/a/b, basically no matter how many parameters I add the url should be generated according to how many items are there in the list.

How do I modify my code for that.

Comment: don't use `format`, use `'/'.join(list_here)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with `"/"` as the separator instead of `str.format()` to concatenate the URL parts. This will work with lists of arbitrary length:

```
def _build_url(list_here):
    pulls_url = "http://test.com/{}".format("/".join(list_here))
    return pulls_url
```

Comment: what if I have a variable which stores the url like

var = "http://test.com"

then how do I add the url using the variable

pulls_url = var +

Comment: I also had one more question suppose my url is like "http://test.com/" already, how do I handle the trailing slash at the end of com so that there are no two slashes like "http://test.com//"   I am creating test cases for this, so had this doubt.

Comment: You can use `var.rstrip("/")` to remove any trailing slashes in the string, then concatenate the rest, e.g.: `var.rstrip("/") + "/" + "/".join(list_here)`